# HTML Button Image Cut Off

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to make a simple button in HTML using an image and basic CSS styling.
When I load up the html file in a browser, it shows the text of the button as well as some of the button image, but whatever falls outside the text gets cut off.

I'd like the button to be fully shown (it's pretty large) with no text at all.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<a href="somepage.html" class="likeAButton">Fake Button</a>
```

And here's my css file:

```
a.likeAButton {
     width: 500px;
     height: 600px;
     background-image: url(./images/buttons/4s_inactive.png);
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
}
a.likeAButton:hover {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(./images/buttons/4s_active.png);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
a.likeAButton:active {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px; 
    background-image: url(./images/buttons/4s_active.png);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so, you just want the 'button' to have the width of the background-image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors are inline by default, so they have no size. Try this:

```
a.likeAButton {
    display: inline-block;
    ... 
}
```

```css
a.likeAButton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x600);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
a.likeAButton:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x600/0000ff);
}
a.likeAButton:active {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x600/ff0000);
}
```

```html
<a href="somepage.html" class="likeAButton"></a>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1sx43gn3/)**

Notice that I stripped most of the style statements from your `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes. There's no need to repeat them.